# Number of nonisomorphic weighted hypergraphs of certain type

Tags: enumerative-combinatorics, hypergraph

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an unlabeled simple hypergraph with weighted vertices and given properties:

1. $|v|⩾max(d(v);\;3)\;∀v∈V$, where $|v|$ denotes weight of vertice $v$ and $d(v):=\#(e:\;v∈e)$ - number of hyperedges that contain $v$;
2. $\#(v:\;v∈e_1∧v∈e_2))⩾2⇔e_1=e_2\;\;∀e_1,e_2∈E$

Let's say, $G':=\{G:\;1)\;and\;2)\;are\;true\;for\;G\}$.

For every $G∈G'$ define $ϕ(G)$ as $\left(∑_\limits{v∈V}|v|\right)−\left(∑_\limits{e∈E}(d(e)−1)\right)$, where $d(e):=\#(v:\;v∈e)$.

$G_n:=\#(G∈G':\;ϕ(G)=n)$

The question is how to find $G_n$ for every $n$. This problem sounds a bit complicated, so, as it seems to be, there is an easier variation of this problem - for labeled hypergraphs. It would be great to learn some approaches to such problems.

Finally, can you please recommend me some literature on this topic?

[Background: $G_n$ is closely related to the number of nonisomorphic configurations of pairwise non-parallel different $n$ straight lines on $ℝ^2$ (Denote this number as $EC_2(n)$). More precisely, $G_n=EC_2(n)−EC_2(n−1)$.]